# Понижение репутации пользователя после переезда на новую платформу

Tags: поддержка, хэшкод, миграция, репутация

На hashcode.ru у меня была репутация 740. сейчас - 730.

Не то что-бы я капризничаю, но все-таки: 10 пунктов - это какая-то комиссия за переезд?

Это массовая проблема или не повезло только мне?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не повезло всем. При переезде происходил пересчет голосов. На SO немного другие оценки за принятые ответы и т.д. Об этом, кстати, предупреждали.
Вам еще повезло, у вас всего 10 разница, у меня почти 900

Comment: Вот-вот 10 это еще смешно). У меня отняло тоже круглую сумму очков от первоначального рейтинга.

Comment: А у меня почему-то ничего не отнялось, только 100 за переезд начислили. Может все мои "плюсанутые" комментарии, которые потом в ответ преобразовали, сработали?