# Виталина сделал(а) более 500 правок, почему у нее только 11 баллов репутации?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, страница-учётной-записи

[Профиль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/22624/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0). Регулярно приходится видеть малые правки от этой участницы (или участника), она (он) является обладателем знака «Главред» за 500 редактирований чужих и необщих сообщений. За каждое редактирование начисляется 2 балла репутации, соответственно, репутация уже должна составлять как минимум 1000, а не 11. Как с таким количеством правок можно иметь столь низкую репутацию?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Виталина - сотрудник минувшей эпохи ХэшКода (`Последнее посещение 25 июл '15`). На ХэшКоде за правки репутацию не давали.

Просто проходите мимо )

Comment: «Сотрудник» — то есть он(а) получал(а) заработную плату на ХэшКоде?

Comment: @Nofate, а все-таки правильное ли правило, когда за правки вообще  дают репутацию? Ну, или хотя бы пусть подобные правки не вытаскивают наверх все старье.

Comment: @avp, (знаю, что я не Nofate) **[1]** Репутацию за правки считаю правильной, поскольку это стимулирует редакторов улучшать Stack Overflow. // По **[2]** моё предложение Вы [уже видели](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2896/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85). Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, это интересный комментарий (и Ваше предложение о галке я уже видел).

Comment: На Хэшкоде не давали, но при миграции [был произведён полный пересчёт репутации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4/208074). Правки всех вопросов были импортированы наряду с другими данными, [история правок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/22624/?tab=activity&sort=revisions) этого участника формируется корректно и в полном объёме, так что странно, что движок SO не учёл её.

Comment: @Arhad +2 дается за "предложенные" правки, требующие утверждения другими участниками. А эти правки обычные, за такие репутация не дается. Правильнее всего воспринимать их как сделанные ромбом, но с низким уровнем репутации.