# Интересная статистика пользователя

Tags: обсуждение

Я случайно наткнулся на профиль [этого пользователя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/22624/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0). Как может быть у пользователя 11 репутации и 10 220 (!!!) правок, если за каждую утвержденную правку дают +2 репутации? Или раньше были другие правила с правками? Просто интересно...

Comment: Это миграция.Тема обсуждалась уже. Поищите по нику

Comment: Это бот походу. Посмотрите на ее комментарии

Comment: @VadimTagil нет, это не бот.

Comment: @Nofate не бот, а ботиня? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вероятно, все правки были ещё до переезда с хешкода на ru.stackoverflow.

Comment: Да, спасибо нашел https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2913/