# Некорректно отображается пользователь у старых вопросов | Old questions have user displayed incorrectly

Tags: дефект, интерфейс

[Для старых вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api?page=30&sort=active&pagesize=15) некорректно отображается последний активный пользователь:

> [image: bug]

Выводится только серый аватар, как будто пользователь удален, но на самом деле он не удален.

---

Old questions have last active user displayed incorrectly. It only displays grayed avatar, as if user is deleted, but in fact it's not.

Comment: Кажется, это особый пользователь: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy там не только где она. Похоже, для всех вопросов с последней активностью до марта '15 года  так отображается (случаем не дата переезда с ХэшКода?)