# Удалить старые служебные профили хэшкода

Tags: предложение, дух-сообщества, хэшкод, удаление-профиля

Если я правильно понимаю, подобные аккаунты:

- [Deleted](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/7905/?tab=profile)
- [Виталина](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/22624/?tab=profile)

остались со времён миграции хэшкода на платформу SE и использовались для каких-то служебных целей, которые, наверное, мог бы делать [Дух](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/) при соответствующем его развитии. Если посмотреть вкладку активности упомянутых участников, то видно, что они использовались как для [стимуляции установки галочек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/22624/?tab=activity&sort=comments&page=1), так и для некоторых, вероятно, [автоматизированных правок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/7905/?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=1) сообщений.

Учитывая при всём этом [несоответствие репутации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/176217) упомянутых "участников" их запротоколированным заслугам, предлагаю удалить упомянутые профили с сайта. Возможно, есть и другие ботовидные аккаунты, используемые для служебных целей во времена ХэшКода, их тоже предлагается удалить.

На всякий случай хочу заметить, что полезные правки, выполненные от лица упомянутых "участников" в любом случае останутся на сайте, т.о. удаление всего лишь обезличит их, что наиболее подходящим образом вяжется с истинной сущностью данных аккаунтов.

В качестве альтернативного решения можно было бы всю активность участников переписать на Духа, но вряд ли это действие осуществимо малой кровью, хотя, может быть, процедура слияние аккаунтов здесь как раз бы подошла.

Comment: У нас же учётные записи удаляют только за грубейшие нарушения. Зачем сносить некриминальные профили, если их наличие не мешает ничему кроме перфекционизма?

Comment: @Arhad а есть уверенность, что данные аккаунты ничего не нарушают? Например, из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/344266/176217) можно понять, что у Deleted существует марионетка. И это только информация, лежащая на поверхности, копнуть поглубже, обязательно появятся новые нюансы. И я так понял, что по поводу объединения с Духом возражений нет.

Comment: А что не так с тем ответом или комментариями под ним? В упор не вижу ничего, кроме просьбы предоставить логи и обновить ядро указанными командами, так как у него есть информация, что это исправленная ошибка в ядре.

Comment: @Arhad обратите внимание к кому обращается отвечающий. Сравните имена, ссылки.

Comment: Уточните, а в чем именно вы усматриваете ***"служебность"*** двух приведенных профилей? Вполне нормальные профили .. да, с нарушениями, а разве это повод к полному удалению? Если так, то и вопрос ставьте иначе, мол "удалить профили старых нарушителей"

Comment: @Kromster максимально достоверную информацию может, наверное, высказать только КМ, как администратор ХэшКода. "Служебность" видна по типовым комментариям и правкам, ссылки на которые я привёл в вопросе. Ну и расхождение по репутации и реальным делам наводит на определённые мысли. Хотя даже у КМ имеется 666 незаслуженных реп, которые он не может вернуть в пул по причине кривой миграции на SE. Но, кмк, удалить или объединить участников с Духом вполне себе доступная задача для КМ, соответствующие инструменты имеются в его распоряжении.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ `обратите внимание к кому обращается отвечающий` — ага, увидел, спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Эти аккаунты принадлежат не ботам, а вполне живым людям. Виталина и Iranda (Deleted) - это редакторы времен хэшкода.

Как сотрудники компании, они вносили правки в обход очереди проверки, и не получали за это репутацию. (Впрочем, очередей проверок тогда вообще не было, полагалась ли репутация за правки - не уверен).

Точно так же сейчас не получают репутацию за правки сотрудники SO, например [Adam Lear](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176103/adam-lear?tab=activity&sort=revisions) - есть несколько правок, а репутация все равно 101.

Давайте не удалять аккаунты живых людей, хотя бы из уважения к их труду.

Comment: Человек не является живым, если у него нет знака "не робот". Про правки я как-то сразу не сообразил, что они выполнены монопольно без утверждения другими участниками. Проецируя прежнюю деятельность аккаунтов на текущие условия можно было бы сказать, что участники имели ромб модератора (не знаю, были ли тогда какие-то видимые знаки отличия). Это быстрее позволило бы понять ситуацию. Но вопрос с репутацией за принятие ответов на чужих вопросах по-прежнему [остается открытым.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291897/339911)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ с репутацией за чужие ответы - все [строго как в справке написано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) - "+2 балла участнику, который принял ответ". Вот разрешат у нас модераторам помечать ответы на чужие вопросы как принятые - будет неисчерпаемый источник репутации для ромбов :)

Comment: справку надо в комплексе рассматривать, а не отрывками. Ну и сложности перевода не стоит сбрасывать со счетов. Одно дело вознаграждение за действие, другое дело - доступ на выполнение действий. При отсутствии доступа не может быть и репутации. А если доступ противоречит настройкам - это уже дыра в безопасности. ("Ну, хоть что-то у нас в безопасности"). И такие дыры стоит воспринимать как баги. Довольно серьёзные баги.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а доступы надо рассматривать на момент совершения действия, а не на момент обсуждения

Comment: @PavelMayorov безусловно. Но доступа на принятие ответа не автором вопроса по концепции SE **не было никогда**

Comment: @αλεχολυτ зато по концепции хешкода такой доступ, скорее всего, таки был.

Comment: @PavelMayorov а если бы за один голос было 100 реп, а не 10, тоже надо было учесть при миграции?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ таки не 10, а 2. Но да, надо было бы учесть даже если бы там было 100. Потому что: это ни на что не влияет и так проще.

Comment: @PavelMayorov учесть как? Оставить старые "очки" на новом движке 1к1? Или выполнить индексацию? Я считаю, что миграция должна учитывать правила принимающего сайта (то есть SE) на момент миграции. И игнорировать любые правила отдающего сайта (то есть хешкода).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ тогда пришлось бы откатить достаточно много действий. На хэшкоде скорее всего были свои правила по правкам, комментариям, удалению и прочему. При миграции переносили состояние и лог действий, а не проигрывали все действия заново. Проигрывание действий заново, с применением новых правил, наверняка бы достаточно сильно исказило результат - где-то галки нельзя ставить было, где-то - комментарии писать, где-то чужие посты править, где-то голоса поплыли бы.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ В любом случае, эти профили сотрудников, и не стоит прямо отображать их репутацию на репутацию обычных участников. Им за действия деньги платили, а обычным участникам - нет :)

Comment: @PashaPash ну, некоторые сотрудники старых и новых эпох получали профит по всем фронтам: реальным и виртуальным.  Поэтому логично было бы виртуальный профит всё же причесать под текущую схему. Перенести репу за галочку автору вопроса, а не сотруднику, который эту галочку поставил. Все понимают, что делать, конечно же, ничего не будут. Но и говорить об этом я тоже не перестану :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ конфисковать виртуальный профит и раздать бедным

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а автору вопроса в этом случае за что репу? Эти +2 - это награда за конкретные действия - постановку галки и подтверждение полезности ответа. Уж кто, а автор вопроса, который на сайт не вернулся и галку не поставил, точно не заслуживает +2 нахаляву. Народ тут старается, правит чужие сообщения ради тех же +2. А вы предлагаете взять и раздать.

Comment: @PashaPash не бедным, а тем, кто заслужил. По справедливости.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ авторы вопросов, не поставившие галку на ответ, не заслужили +2 по текущим правилам SO.

Comment: @PashaPash значит надо снять галки и будет полный перерасчет и справедливость.

Comment: @PashaPash а вообще, так ли важно КТО её поставил? Например, мог поставить бот, работающий от лица учетки ТС. Вы же не будете утверждать, что в таком случае репу надо боту давать.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я только утверждаю, что в этом случае репутацию не стоит давать топикастеру, т.к. эти +2 - это поощрение за вполне конкретное поведение, которое топикастер не проявил. Точно так же, как в случае +2 за правку - они достаются тому, кто правку предложил, а не автору сообщения. Хотя с точки зрения результата - тоже все равно, КТО предложил правку.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Ну и опять же, если неважно, кто поставил галку - то все отлично. Человек мог поставить галку по существовавшим правилам, поставил, получил за это +2. Сейчас у администрации (у работников SE) тоже, наверняка, есть возможность взять и поставить галку. Просто они ей не пользуются, т.к. тут так не принято.

Answer (score 4):

Не вижу смысла их удалять. Никому не мешают и даже что-то делали в прошлом.

Comment: Ох уж эти однострочные ответы, неподкреплённые вообще ничем. Как можно утверждать от лица всех, что "никому не мешает", если вот хотя бы уже мне мешают? "что-то делали в прошлом" - это о чём? Раскройте, пожалуйста, своё мнение подробнее. Пока только лишь могу минусануть за нераскрытие позиции. Подобные ответы от модераторов я не могу считать приемлемыми.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ так может он не как модератор отвечал? )

Comment: @Suvitruf был не при исполнении? :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ и у модератора бывает выходной (;

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы удалить что-то, даже бота, нужны какие-то основания. Обычно, насколько я понимаю, удаляются аккаунты, созданные только с целью нарушения правил и не имеющие полезного вклада. Использование вторых аккаунтов для запуска ботов само по себе не запрещено (см. [пример на EN SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356509/8674428)), поэтому оснований удалять такие аккаунты нет.

Comment: Ну, основания довольно легко найти. Например, [принятие чужого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/410778/timeline) и получение за это репутации, которая полагалась [автору вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/410657/timeline).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ это же просто баг. Необязательно удалять Виталину, чтобы пофиксить его, досточно удалить все некорректные принятия из таблицы голосов.

Comment: Просто баг? Институт репутации должен быть незыблем на SO. Необязательно вообще обсуждать всё это, но коли уж обсуждаем, самый простой способ мне видится именно в удалении подобных аккаунтов (хорошая альтернатива - объединить с Духом), чем пытаться как-то точечно исправить ситуацию. Никто не будет фиксить отдельные моменты, связанные с нарушением логики, совершенных аккаунтом действий и повлекшими за этим последствиями. А вот выполнить ручное удаление, причём может быть даже от лица самого аккаунта - вполне может быть простым. Надо только чтобы КМ пароль вспомнил от своих сокпупетов.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Так вы же сами сказали, что некорректные принятия не только у ботов, но и у самого аккаунта Николаса есть. Вот здесь например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/116/timeline - вопрос stanislav, ответ stanislav, а принят Nicolas Chabanovsky♦. Его то вы никак не удалите. Так что надо удалять (или исправлять) именно некорректные принятия как факт, а не отдельные аккаунты.

Comment: "Его то вы никак не удалите." Если владелец профиля решит действовать единообразно для всех аккаунтов, то почему бы нет? :) Но если серьёзно, наличие неразрешимых проблем в одном аккаунте (не стоит удалять родной профиль КМ) не обязательно должно блокировать возможность такого удаления у других, по сути вымерших аккаунтов.